# Can I sell Windows 7 Professional installs/keys that I no longer use?

Tags: windows-7, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-installing-windows-7-or-vista-does-the-language-version-architecture-64)

I purchased two copies of Windows 7 Professional and have since upgraded to Windows 7 Ultimate for both the associated machines.

Can I legally sell these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** I'm not a lawyer!

You may want to read the EULA, especially Section 18:

```
18. TRANSFER TO A THIRD PARTY. 

a. Software Other Than Windows Anytime Upgrade. The first user of the software may make 
a one time transfer of the software and this agreement, by transferring the original media, the 
certificate of authenticity, the product key and the proof of purchase directly to a third party. The 
first user must remove the software before transferring it separately from the computer. The first 
user may not retain any copies of the software. 

b. Windows Anytime Upgrade Software. You may transfer the software directly to a third party 
only with the licensed computer. You may not keep any copies of the software or any earlier 
edition. 

c. Other Requirements. Before any permitted transfer, the other party must agree that this 
agreement applies to the transfer and use of the software.
```

Comment: Thanks - looks like I am good to go via 18.a.  Only concern is I can't imagine there's an actual market for the keys since these were digital purchases/downloads.  I'll probably use them to upgrade friends.